# Deriving matrix definition of unitary matrices from a definition based on norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, unitary-matrices

Let a matrix $A$ be unitary if $$||Ax||_2=||x||_2$$ for any $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$. We see that
$$||Ax||_2=x^*A^*Ax=x^*x=||x||_2$$ which implies $A^*Ax=x\longrightarrow A^*A=I$.

How do you derive the fact that $AA^*=I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^\ast A = I$ then multiplying $A$ to the left on both sides yields $A A^\ast A = A$ and multiplying $A^{-1}$ to the right gives $A A^\ast = I.$

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble because I didn't realize my definition implies that all unitary matrices have full rank and are thus invertible.